# Guice: value of field annotated with @Named is null

Tags: java, guice

I have a class in which I declare my static constants:

```
public final class ConfigOptions {
    public static final String FILE_PATH_SERVER = "/home/user/me/somefile";
}
```

Then I use Guice to bind it in my `ServletModule`:

```
public class MyServletModule extends ServletModule {
    bind(String.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("filePath"))
        .toInstance(ConfigOptions.FILE_PATH_SERVER);

    // Also tried
    // bindConstant().annotatedWith(Names.named("filePath")).to(ConfigOptions.FILE_PATH_SERVER)

    // ... other bindings
}
```

My `GuiceServletContextListener`:

```
public class MyServletContextListener extends GuiceServletContextListener {

    @Override
    protected Injector getInjector() {
        return Guice.createInjector(new MyServletModule());
    }
}
```

Finally, I try to use `filePath`:

```
public class MyClass {

    @Inject
    @Named("filePath")
    private String filePath;

    public MyClass() { ... }

    public void doSomething() {
        someotherThing.setFilePath(filePath);  // But filePath is null
    }
}
```

I mostly follwed the method shown [here](http://blog.japila.pl/2011/01/abstractmodule-bindconstant-inject-and-named-in-google-guice/) but not sure if I'm missing something.

Additionally, I've made sure that the correct `import com.google.inject.name.Named` is imported.

Comment: Can you confirm that you are letting Guice create your instances of MyClass, rather than instantiating it yourself with `new MyClass()`? With the field injection as you have it, if the class is never requested through the injector, the field will silently remain `null`. Switching to constructor injection will also help make it obvious whether the class is being provided through Guice.

Comment: Ahh, you hit the nail on the head! I was not letting Guice create MyClass (Guice noob here). Injecting MyClass instead solved it. You should probably make it an answer. Thanks :)

Comment: Done. Glad to help, and good luck with the rest of your project!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Confirm that you are letting Guice create your instances of MyClass, rather than instantiating them yourself with `new MyClass()`. Even if a field is marked with `@Inject`, Guice can only set the value if Guice is responsible for creating the instance containing it*. With the field injection as you have it, if the class is never requested through the injector, the field will silently remain null.

Switching to constructor injection will also help make it obvious whether the class is being provided through Guice, because changing the constructor will inherently break any direct calls without breaking Guice-created references:

```
public class MyClass {

  private final String filePath;

  @Inject public MyClass(@Named("filePath") String filePath) {
    this.filePath = filePath;
    // ...
  }

  // ...
}
```

---

*You may also cajole Guice into injecting into an existing instance using [Injector.injectMembers(instance)](https://google-guice.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/inject/Injector.html#injectMembers%28java.lang.Object%29) or [Binder.requestInjection(instance)](https://google-guice.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/inject/Binder.html#requestInjection%28java.lang.Object%29). These are uncommon, and may make it hard to follow where you construct and inject the instance, but may prove useful in legacy code and a few other cases.